# Table vertical-align in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The problem is when using `<table>` (or a `<div>` with `display:table`), how can I center this table element vertically?

I used this method of vertical centering:

```
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
overflow: auto;
```

When using this method in Chrome (any Webkit or Blink), it works well, but not in Firefox.
When running this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Mu4yd) in Chrome, the table is vertically centered, while in Firefox, it sticks at the top.

Is there something that should be added to make it work in Firefox? Or, is there any other alternative method to vertically center a table in both browsers (at least)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a responsive-friendly and flexible solution. If you don't know the width or height of the div, you can use this CSS3 code:

**[Vertical align center with transform - fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHTn6/1/)**

```
.valign{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It works. But isn't the `transform` expensive? Isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: I use this code a lot, and I think it is a "lightweight" solution in the world of CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can center it using the following method

```
#tablelo{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; 
    display: table;       
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Mu4yd/5/)

Comment: But it's not general. It requires changing the margin size whenever the table size is changed.